# Floating point formatted to base 16

Tags: format, lisp, hex

I am writing a Lisp program to approximate pi using a Spigot algorithm, one that finds a single digit at a time without needing any digits previously calculated.  This one:

[image: Equation]

Supposedly goes one **hexadecimal** digit at a time, however testing it out we have consecutive calls (iterating over i) yielding Lisp's well-known **fractions**:

2F/F
6A/333
33D/4CB3
13C/3B79

And so forth.  This is achieved using the format function with the ~x parameter:

```
 (format t "~x" [some number])
```

Alternatively,

```
 (format t "~d" [some number])
```

Yields the **base 10 decimals**:

3.1333334
0.12942614
0.042220525
0.020755336

However **I want decimals in hexadecimal**, for example if one round yielded 0.5 then I want 0.8;  if the base 10 is 0.75 then I want 0.C.  That way I can calculate see each hexadecimal digit of pi separately, which was my original reason for choosing this Spigot algorithm.  I could also use a **fraction of the form (n / 16^k)**, because this could easily be converted into a hexadecimal decimal.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: It sounds like you need a custom numeric data type, something akin to `decimal` in C# or Java, but base 16 instead of base 10.  Or simply an array of bytes containing your hexadecimal digits.

Comment: I don't think that's the answer.  This is all about formatting; I didn't need a custom data type to get hex fractions or base-10 decimals.  All I want is to have both hex and decimals in a single format, both together on one single number.

Comment: So basically your entire question boils down to "How do I format a floating point number in hexadecimal format in Lisp?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Essentially, yes.  I just wanted to put some context on to 1) show various things that are almost what I want but not quite and 2) show why I want it.

Comment: That all makes sense. It still boils down to a custom function to generate a "hexadecimal point" number as a string that you can "print".

Comment: @mbratch Ah, I see.  I was hoping `format` had some way of doing this, but, as verdammelt points out down below, there probably isn't a way.  *sigh*  I guess it wouldn't be too difficult to write a custom function for it.

Comment: It's pretty easy, especially in Lisp. Once you have your < 1 value, you just multiply by 16, take the integer part as the hex digit, take the remaining fraction, and repeat that process for as many digits as you need.

Comment: @mbratch I guess it is pretty easy.  But it seems like `format` shouldn't limit you to one of two non-mutually-exclusive features (base-16 and floating-point).

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's true in many languages in the handling of formatting numbers. It's non-orthogonal. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~x` and `~d` are formatting routines for integers, not floating point numbers (emphasis added):

> #### [22.3.2.2 Tilde D: Decimal](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cbb.htm)
>
> An arg, which should be an integer, is printed in decimal radix. ~D
>   will never put a decimal point after the number. … **If arg is not an
>   integer, it is printed in ~A format and decimal base.**

> #### [22.3.2.5 Tilde X: Hexadecimal](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cbe.htm)
>
> This is just like ~D but prints in hexadecimal radix (radix 16)
>   instead of decimal.

(*As an aside, I think there's actually some ambiguity about what base `~x` should print its argument in if it's not an integer.  It comes down to whether "just like ~D but prints in hexadecimal" overrides just the integer arguments, or the all arguments.*)

But what are these format directives actually doing?  They're binding the values of `*print-base*` and `*print-radix*` and the documentation on those says that they only affect the printing of *rational numbers*:

> #### [Variable `*PRINT-BASE*`, `*PRINT-RADIX*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pr_bas.htm#STprint-radixST)
>
> `*print-base*` and `*print-radix*` control the printing of rationals. The value of `*print-base*` is called the current output base.
>
> The value of `*print-base*` is the radix in which the printer will print
>   rationals. For radices above 10, letters of the alphabet are used to
>   represent digits above 9.
>
> If the value of `*print-radix*` is true, the printer will print a radix
>   specifier to indicate the radix in which it is printing a rational
>   number. The radix specifier is always printed using lowercase letters.
>   If `*print-base*` is 2, 8, or 16, then the radix specifier used is #b,
>   #o, or #x, respectively. For integers, base ten is indicated by a trailing decimal point instead of a leading radix specifier; for
>   ratios, #10r is used.

Now, there are some floating point directives for `format`, and they're listed in [22.3.3 FORMAT Floating-Point Printers](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cc.htm).  Unfortunately, none of those do anything with different bases or radices, so you won't be able to print hexadecimals with them.

It looks like you'll end up having to write your own output routine, or find one in a library.  Of course, you should probably implement it as a function that can be used with [~slash](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_ced.htm), so that you can still write things like:

```
(format t "~/hexadecimal/" 1/16)
```

It's actually not too hard to do this, so here's one way (but I won't guarantee that there are no bugs in this).  It wouldn't be too hard to extend this to work with a user-provided base, and to make it a bit more like the other floating point printers (e.g., to add a `+` for positive numbers if `@` is provided, and to add support for widths, etc.).

```
(in-package #:common-lisp-user)

(defun hexadecimal (stream number colonp atp &rest args)
  (declare (ignore colonp atp args))
  (when (< number 0)
    (write-char #\- stream)
    (setq number (- number)))
  (multiple-value-bind (quotient remainder) (floor number 1.0)
    (format stream "~x." quotient)
    (do () ((zerop remainder))
      (multiple-value-setq (quotient remainder)
        (floor (* 16 remainder)))
      (format stream "~x" quotient))))
```

With this, you get the expected results:

```
(LOOP :FOR NUM :FROM -1/2 :TO 1/2 :BY 1/256
      :COLLECT (FORMAT NIL "~/hexadecimal/" NUM))
;=>
("-0.8" "-0.7F" "-0.7E" "-0.7D" "-0.7C" "-0.7B" "-0.7A" "-0.79" "-0.78"
 "-0.77" "-0.76" "-0.75" "-0.74" "-0.73" "-0.72" "-0.71" "-0.7" "-0.6F"
 ...
 "-0.1D" "-0.1C" "-0.1B" "-0.1A" "-0.19" "-0.18" "-0.17" "-0.16" "-0.15"
 "-0.14" "-0.13" "-0.12" "-0.11" "-0.1" "-0.0F" "-0.0E" "-0.0D" "-0.0C"
 "-0.0B" "-0.0A" "-0.09" "-0.08" "-0.07" "-0.06" "-0.05" "-0.04" "-0.03"
 "-0.02" "-0.01" "0." "0.01" "0.02" "0.03" "0.04" "0.05" "0.06" "0.07"
 "0.08" "0.09" "0.0A" "0.0B" "0.0C" "0.0D" "0.0E" "0.0F" "0.1" "0.11"
 ...
 "0.6C" "0.6D" "0.6E" "0.6F" "0.7" "0.71" "0.72" "0.73" "0.74" "0.75"
 "0.76" "0.77" "0.78" "0.79" "0.7A" "0.7B" "0.7C" "0.7D" "0.7E" "0.7F"
 "0.8")
```

In fact, it's really not hard to make this a bit more generic.  Since we can pass arguments to format directives, we can take the printing base as an argument, *and* we can bind `*print-base*` to it at the same time, so we can just write in the body of the function, and we can do our numeric work with `*print-base*`:

```
(in-package #:common-lisp-user)

(defun floating (stream number colonp atp 
                 &optional (*print-base* 10) (num-digits 10)
                 &rest args)
  (declare (ignore colonp args))
  ;; If the number is negative, print the #\- and invert the number.
  ;; Otherwise, the number is non-negative, and if an @ was provided
  ;; we print a leading #\+.
  (cond
    ((minusp number)
     (write-char #\- stream)
     (setq number (- number)))
    (atp
     (write-char #\+ stream)))
  ;; Print number, which is now guaranteed to be positive.  Begin by
  ;; taking its integer part and printing it, followed by a point.
  ;; Then, pull individual places and write them.  This continues,
  ;; updating quotient and remainder by multiplying the remainder by
  ;; the base and taking the floor again until either the remainder
  ;; becomes zero, or we've reached the maximum number of digits.
  (multiple-value-bind (quotient remainder) (floor number 1.0)
    (write quotient :stream stream)
    (write-char #\. stream)
    (do ((num-digits num-digits (1- num-digits))) 
        ((or (zerop remainder) (zerop num-digits)))
      (multiple-value-setq (quotient remainder)
        (floor (* *print-base* remainder)))
      (write quotient :stream stream))))
```

```
;; 1/2 base 10 is a repeating decimal in base 3.
CL-USER> (format t "~3/floating/" 1/2)
0.1111111111

;; so is -1/2, and asking for more numbers gives them to us
CL-USER> (format t "~3,15/floating/" -1/2)
-0.111111111111111

;; but 1/3 base 10 is non repeating in base 3
CL-USER> (format t "~3,15/floating/" 1/3)
0.1

;; it's non-repeating in base 6, as well
CL-USER> (format t "~6,15/floating/" 1/3)
0.2

;; base 16 still works
CL-USER> (format t "~16/floating/" 189/256)
0.BD

;; and the @ will give us a leading +
CL-USER> (format t "~16@/floating/" 189/256)
+0.BD
```

Comment: @verdammelt There's a version for arbitrary bases, now, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible with the built in features of `format`<sup>1</sup> However I'm sure someone with some fancy math could implement a function to do this.

---

<sup>1. I tested with SBCL v1.1.14. I tried `(format t "~x" (coerce 2/32 'float))` which was the same as `(format t "~d" (coerce 2/32 'float))`</sup>

Comment: But ~x is only for integers anyhow, so this isn't quite an answer. The docs say that ~d is for integers, and that ~x is just like ~d, except with a different print radix.  ~d and ~x aren't supposed to be applied to floating point numbers in the first place.

Comment: Damn! That is a good point - I missed that in the documentation! So SBCL went a bit further and allows rationals to be formatted with ~d and ~x.

Comment: Well, the docs for ~d do say "If arg is not an integer, it is printed in ~A format and decimal base."  and that "[~x] is just like ~D but prints in hexadecimal radix (radix 16) instead of decimal."  So it's not surprising that the object is printable, although it's a little ambiguous, in my opinion, what base non-integers should be printed in with ~x.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted?  It clearly states that what the OP wants is not possible with format and gives an alternative solution.

Comment: @MegaWidget It's not downvoted anymore, but it's still focused on ~x and ~d which are for integer formatting, not floating point formatting.  It's pointing out that ~x and ~d don't do the job, but it doesn't even consider the floating point format directives (although, they're not sufficient either).